# How to divide big numbers more accurately

Tags: python, primes, division

I'm creating a program which checks if the number `numb` is prime and if it's not then it factorizes the number into prime numbers and prints out the factors but the problem fails with big numbers.

```
for n in primes:
    if numb % n == 0:
        a = 0
        while numb % n == 0:
            a += 1
            factors[n] = a
            prime = False
            numb = numb / n
```

When `numb` is big (18 digits long) the program fails at the `numb = numb / n` and it doesn't divide correctly *(for example 231351651321912318 / 2 = 1.1567582566095616e+17)*

Numbers always should divide without any decimal places so can I make that the result is more accurate?

Comment: You could use `numb // n` since you already know that `numb % n == 0`

Comment: BTW, `factors[n] = a` and `prime = False` don't need to be inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `/` calls for floating-point division and that causes your operands to be divided as floating-point numbers. 18 digits is at the limit of floating-point precision. For integer division use `//` instead.